# SNMP GetResponse in a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, snmp

I want to get the SNMP Getresponse in a datagridview..I have bind an Array in the datagrid..But the problem is i m not getting any response in datagrid instead i m getting a message box that shows "No results received"..

How can I get my Snmp GetResponse in a datagridView?

Here is the code

```
Private Sub DataGridView2_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellContentClick
 Dim dt As New DataTable()
 Dim snmp As New SimpleSnmp
 Dim kvp As KeyValuePair(Of Oid, AsnType)
 Dim result As Dictionary(Of Oid, AsnType)
 dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column1", GetType(SimpleSnmp)))
 dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column2", GetType(Dictionary(Of Oid, AsnType))))
 dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column3", GetType(KeyValuePair(Of Oid, AsnType))))

 Dim dr As DataRow
 dr = dt.NewRow()
 dr("Column1") = New SimpleSnmp(DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString, DataGridView1.Rows(3).Cells(1).Value.ToString)

 dr("Column2") = snmp.Get(SnmpVersion.Ver1, New String() {DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(1).Value.ToString()})


 If Not snmp.Valid Then
  MessageBox.Show("Invalid hostname/community")
 End If

 If result IsNot Nothing Then

  For Each kvp In result
  dr(0) = SnmpConstants.GetTypeName(kvp.Value.Type)
  dr(1) = kvp.Key.ToString
  dr(2) = kvp.Value.ToString()
  Next kvp
 Else
  MessageBox.Show("No results received")

 End If


 dt.Rows.Add(dr)
 DataGridView2.DataSource = dt

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

SimpleSnmp is not a common class. Microsoft .NET Framework does not contain such a class, so you probably find it somewhere on the Internet.

Then you would have to debug on your own if you have its source code.